# Update All via CriteriaUpdate fails, whereat NativeQuery succeeds

Tags: java, eclipselink, criteria-api

I have an native query that counts the connections to an `TaxaCatalog` via my N:M Table `TaxaLinkTaxaCatalogs`

NOTE: in the mapping those Tables are only Mapped, they are not linked/connected, as M:N is only working with `weaving`, which is **not** possible in my current configuration (not dynamic and also not static)!

```
<named-native-query name="UpdateTaxaCountForAllTaxaCatalogs">
    <query>UPDATE tTaxaCatalogs
            SET tacTaxaCount = (
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM tTaxaLinkTaxaCatalogs
                WHERE tTaxaCatalogs.tacIdCatalog = tTaxaLinkTaxaCatalogs.tltIdCatalog)
    </query>
</named-native-query>
```

which outputs:

```
[EL Fine]: sql: Connection(236858974)--UPDATE tTaxaCatalogs
                SET tacTaxaCount = (
                    SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM tTaxaLinkTaxaCatalogs
                    WHERE tTaxaCatalogs.tacIdCatalog = tTaxaLinkTaxaCatalogs.tltIdCatalog)
```

and the values in database are updated.

i tried to implement exactly the same with Criteria API:

```
EntityManager em = ...// get EntityManager from Testsystem
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
// UPDATE tTaxaCatalogs
CriteriaUpdate<TaxaCatalogImpl> updateQuery = cb.createCriteriaUpdate(TaxaCatalogImpl.class);
Root rootTaxaCatalog = updateQuery.from(TaxaCatalogImpl.class);

// subQuery = 
Subquery<Long> sq = updateQuery.subquery(Long.class);
// FROM tTaxaLinkTaxaCatalogs
Root<TaxaLinkTaxaCatalogImpl> rootTaxaLinkTaxaCatalog = sq.from(TaxaLinkTaxaCatalogImpl.class);
// SELECT COUNT(*)
        sq.select(cb.count(rootTaxaLinkTaxaCatalog.get(TaxaLinkTaxaCatalogEnum.taxonId.name())));
// WHERE tTaxaCatalogs.tacIdCatalog = tTaxaLinkTaxaCatalogs.tltIdCatalog
sq.where(//
    cb.equal(//
        rootTaxaCatalog.<Integer> get(TaxaCatalogEnum.id.name()), //
        rootTaxaLinkTaxaCatalog.<Integer> get(TaxaLinkTaxaCatalogEnum.catalogId.name())//
    )//
);//
// SET tacTaxaCount = subQuery
updateQuery.set(rootTaxaCatalog.get(TaxaCatalogEnum.taxaCount.name()), sq);

em.getTransaction().begin();
try {
    Query query = em.createQuery(updateQuery);
    String sql = query.unwrap(JpaQuery.class).getDatabaseQuery().getSQLString();
    System.out.println("SQL Query for Update is");
    System.out.println(sql);

    int result = query.executeUpdate();
    assertEquals(ExpectedResults, result);
} catch (Exception e) {
    em.getTransaction().rollback();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

which results in the following Output:

```
SQL Query for Update is
null
[EL Warning]: Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-6168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Query failed to prepare, unexpected error occurred: [java.lang.NullPointerException].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Query: UpdateAllQuery(referenceClass=TaxaCatalogImpl )
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.prepareFailed(QueryException.java:1596)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:872)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ModifyAllQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ModifyAllQuery.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:298)
    at at.biooffice.osgi.service.eclipselink.impl.TestUpdateAllTaxaCountsOnTaxaCatalog.UpdateTaxaCountForAllTaxaCatalogsCriteria(TestUpdateAllTaxaCountsOnTaxaCatalog.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SubSelectExpression.printSQL(SubSelectExpression.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ExpressionSQLPrinter.translateExpression(ExpressionSQLPrinter.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ExpressionSQLPrinter.printExpression(ExpressionSQLPrinter.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLUpdateAllStatement.buildSimple(SQLUpdateAllStatement.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLUpdateAllStatement.buildCall(SQLUpdateAllStatement.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.buildCallFromStatement(ClassDescriptor.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.setCallFromStatement(StatementQueryMechanism.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.prepareUpdateAll(StatementQueryMechanism.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.prepareUpdateAll(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2287)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.UpdateAllQuery.prepare(UpdateAllQuery.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:666)
    ... 33 more

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-6168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Query failed to prepare, unexpected error occurred: [java.lang.NullPointerException].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Query: UpdateAllQuery(referenceClass=TaxaCatalogImpl )
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:308)
    at at.biooffice.osgi.service.eclipselink.impl.TestUpdateAllTaxaCountsOnTaxaCatalog.UpdateTaxaCountForAllTaxaCatalogsCriteria(TestUpdateAllTaxaCountsOnTaxaCatalog.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-6168] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150916-55dc7c3): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: Query failed to prepare, unexpected error occurred: [java.lang.NullPointerException].
Internal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Query: UpdateAllQuery(referenceClass=TaxaCatalogImpl )
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException.prepareFailed(QueryException.java:1596)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:872)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ModifyAllQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ModifyAllQuery.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:298)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SubSelectExpression.printSQL(SubSelectExpression.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ExpressionSQLPrinter.translateExpression(ExpressionSQLPrinter.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.ExpressionSQLPrinter.printExpression(ExpressionSQLPrinter.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLUpdateAllStatement.buildSimple(SQLUpdateAllStatement.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.expressions.SQLUpdateAllStatement.buildCall(SQLUpdateAllStatement.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.descriptors.ClassDescriptor.buildCallFromStatement(ClassDescriptor.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.setCallFromStatement(StatementQueryMechanism.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.prepareUpdateAll(StatementQueryMechanism.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.prepareUpdateAll(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2287)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.UpdateAllQuery.prepare(UpdateAllQuery.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.checkPrepare(DatabaseQuery.java:666)
    ... 33 more
```

i can't find my mistake. can you?

Comment: Try removing the attempt to get the SQL before executing the query as it performs cloning internally - and is wrong anyway, as the query needs to be prepared before you can get the SQL from it as per https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/JPA#How_to_get_the_SQL_for_a_Query.3F

Comment: removing the lines to get the SQL does not have any effect. still the same exception gets thrown. (i add those lines only to verify the query while under development)

Comment: @lumo What was the solution?

Comment: @Nathan I am sorry, but I found no solution, otherwise it would have been posted here.